# Motors for linear and rotary motion

Tags: arduino, iot, servo

I have a use case where I should apply a push action and then rotate 45 degrees or so. I want to know what kind of motors I should look for! (google talks about servo motor / potentio motor, etc.). I want to listen from experts on this.

It is an IoT exercise I am working on with my software knowledge. I have Arduino Uno kit, but I can use a better / different one if needed.

I need suggestion on motors (different strengths), their precise control and a way to confirm the action completion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware recommendation, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino is the easiest solution, they already have prepared templates for controlling a servo motor that lets you do what you want in no time. Basically you can just pass the angle value in an arduino function.

Servo motors are quite easy as well to control, for some projects i used some small plastic servos with plastic gears (the cheapest in the market), for testing purposes they totally do the job with no price:

http://www.micropik.com/PDF/SG90Servo.pdf

Better quality servo with metal gears:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1142

There are some servos that don't have closed loop control, and can be used using the some PWM signals but acting with continuous rotation:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/154

Have fun !

Comment: Can you share any reference to an example linear motion (push action)? I believe the same is possible with Servo meter!! And also can you share any details about torque needed to rotate a fan controller and a door handle? Any tools to measure this?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is using a ServoMotor

to control that you will need to use a PWM module, am not sure if Arduino can do that but you can for sure check that

[image]

another option can be a Stepper motor but those are more demanded to be controlled since you will need more ioPins and you always need to have an intern counter that represents the bits on the coils in the motor...